# Altenating images in image view using thread

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code to toggle between two images in a image view. I am not using GCD because this code is part of an already existing system that has been coded this way.

```
- (void)updateimage { 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.fileno % 2 == 0) {
            self.imageViewTest.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image7.png"];
        }
        else {
           self.imageViewTest.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image8.png"];
        }
       [self.imageViewTest setNeedsDisplay];
        self.filenolabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.fileno];
    });

}
- (void)calculateFileNo {
while (1) {
    self.fileno ++;
    sleep(1);

    [self updateimage];

 }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.detectionThread = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self  selector:@selector(calculateFileNo) object:nil] ;
    [self.detectionThread setName:@"NewThread"];
    [self.detectionThread start];
 }
```

The filenolabel label displays the right no for each loop. But at times the images do not toggle properly. The same image is displayed for 2 or 3 iterations of the loop. I want the image to be toggled for each iteration. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `setNeedsDisplay`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment place is a problem 'self.fileno ++;' -> move it to dispatcher.

```
- (void)updateimage { 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (self.fileno % 2 == 0) {
            self.imageViewTest.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image7.png"];
        }
        else {
           self.imageViewTest.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image8.png"];
        }
       [self.imageViewTest setNeedsDisplay];
        self.filenolabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.fileno];
    self.fileno ++;
    });

}
- (void)calculateFileNo {
while (1) {

    sleep(1);

    [self updateimage];

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase your file no inside the main thread.

```
     self.fileno++;
```

You should only be calling setNeedsDisplay if you override drawRect in a subclass of UImageView which is basically a custom view drawing something on the screen, like lines, images, or shapes like a rectangle.

So you should call setNeedsDisplay when you make changes to few variables on which this drawing depends and for view to represent that change , you need to call this method which internally will give a call to drawRect and redraw the components.

When you change an imageView of image or make changes to any subview, you need call this method.

```
    - (void)updateimage {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (self.fileno % 2 == 0) {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image7.png"];
            }
            else {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image8.png"];
            }
            [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
            self.fileno ++; // Increament your file no inside the main thread.
            self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.fileno];
        });
    }
```